# Why variable declare outside function is not accessing inside function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

When the page loaded,I want to display only  two comments at first.But when i clicked on the button ,i want to increase the display number of comments by two.But nothing happen as my wish.I have tried but my code is not working.It work reverse as i want.I display all the comments when page loaded and display only two comments when i click on button.Any ideas how i can fix  this bugs.Thanks  is advance...

Here is demo code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.d-none {
  display:none;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-comment">
      <button class="view_next_comment">View Only Limited</button>
      <h1>This is comment one.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-comment">
      <button class="view_next_comment">View Only Limited</button>
      <h1>This is comment one.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment two.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment">
      <h1>This is comment three.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let start1=0;
    let limit = 2;
    function show_few_comments(start1,limit){
      $('.post').each(function(){
        var comments = $(this).find('.post-comment');
        var comments_length = comments.length;
    //alert(limit)
    if( comments_length > limit ){
      for( var start1=0; start1<comments_length; start1++ ){
        if(start1>=limit){
          $(comments[start1]).addClass('d-none');
        }
      }
    }
  })
    }
    $(document).on('click','.view_next_comment',function(){
      var start1 =start1+limit;
      show_few_comments(start1,limit);
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're *shadowing* your outer `start1` with an inner one because you have an inner declaration (`var start1 =start1+limit;`). If you want to use `start1` in that callback, use a different name for the local variable. If you want to use the outer `start1`, remove the `var`.

Comment: *(There has to be a good dupetarget for this...)*

Answer (score 2):

You're *shadowing* your outer `start1` with an inner one because you have an inner declaration (`var start1 =start1+limit;`), here's a simpler example:

```js
var start1 = 0;

function example() {
    var start1 = start1 + 2;
    // Shows `NaN`, not `2`, because this inner `start1` initially
    // has the value `undefined`, and `undefined + 2` is `NaN`
    console.log(start1);
}

example();
```

If you want to use the outer `start1` in that callback, use a different name for the local variable (or if you don't need a local, just don't have one. For example:

```js
var start1 = 0;

function example() {
    var myStart = start1 + 2;
    // Shows `2`
    console.log(myStart);
}

example();
```

**Note:** I've used `var` in those examples because you did in your question, but I recommend not using `var` in new code; use `let` or `const` instead, they have several advantages over the old `var`, one of which might have helped you with this problem, because

```js
var start1 = 0;

function example() {
    let start1 = start1 + 2; // <== Causes error
    console.log(start1);
}

example();
```

That causes an error because unlike `var`-declared variables, `let`-declared variables can't be *read* in their own initializer expresssion.